# Intent for opening the watch face picker in Android Wear

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os

As part of an app I'm working on, I'd like to programmatically open the watch face picker on an Android Wear watch (typically achieved by long-pressing on the current watch face). Note that I'm not trying to programmatically change the watch face, but just open the picker so that the user can choose a new watch face.

I'm familiar with using intents to start activities in Android, and I believe I need to do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("???");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I just don't know what to substitute in for "???" in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch faces are just specialized wallpapers, so you can use all the Android facilities that are available for wallpapers. In this case you want to use [`Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER) like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SET_WALLPAPER);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Wallpaper"));
```

Comment: This is doesn't work for me. It just says there's no apps that support this.

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER);
startActivity(intent);
```

See [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html)

Comment: This code actually worked for me. It should be marked as the correct answer.